How to serialize domains in XM Cloud
Is there a way to serialize domain in XMCloud? When we deploy to an environment our created domain is removed, so we had to manually add the domain again. I couldn't find documentations on how to serialize a domain, however when serializing roles we are defining the domain, is this an issue with the serialization itself?

I realize that domains are created in the Domains.config file. Here are the example:

Domain.config file content before create a new domain.



Add a domain in XM Cloud.



Domain.config file after creation.


So, I'm afraid that you can't serialize domains. Maybe, trying to access that file in the deploy pipeline to promote it between environments could solve your problem, but as XM Cloud is a Saas product, and this file is part of the environment, I'm not sure if we can do that. It's a good candidate to raise a support question.
