Creating a transformation configuration file or xdt for defining a Domain in Sitecore Domain Manager
I'm trying to create a configuration file to create a domain in XMC, following this guide - https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/configure-your-xm-cloud-environment.html
How do I compose the config.xdt file for creating a domain in the domain manager?
I tried copying how it is defined in the inetpub/wwwroot/App_config/Security/Domains.config but had no luck.

Hope this helps https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/37888/how-to-serialize-domains-in-xm-cloud
